# Django HTML POST parameters causes NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django, post

I have an HTML post with two drop down lists, I want to send selected `Country` in those lists to the `search()` method that's in `views.py` and then send me to the `results` view. Whenever I add `government` and `location` as parameters for the html POST action or add their value in the search regex, I try this I get a `NoReverseMatch` from my `index` page:

> Reverse for 'search' with arguments '('', '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P[A-Z]{3})/(?P[A-Z]{3})/']

and I don't what I'm doing wrong to cause this error. (See comments in code)

appname/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .models import Country, Embassy
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse


def index(request):
    country = Country.objects.filter()
    template = loader.get_template('appname/index.html')
    context = {'countries': country}
    return render(request, 'appname/index.html', context)

def results(request, government, location):
    return HttpResponse("Here are the Embassies sent by %s, located in %s." % (government, location))

def search(request):
    countries  = Country.objects.all()
    form = request.POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            selected_government = get_object_or_404(pk=request.POST['government'])
        except (KeyError, Country.DoesNotExist):
            return render(request, 'appname/index.html', {
                'error_message': "You didn't select a government.",
            })
        try:
            selected_location = get_object_or_404(pk=request.POST['location'])
        except (KeyError, Country.DoesNotExist):
            return render(request, 'appname/index.html', {
                'error_message': "You didn't select a location.",
            })
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appname:results', args=(selected_government.code,selected_location.code,)))
```

appname/templates/appname/index.html:

```
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

# government and location in the form action causes a NoReverse Match
<form action="{% url 'appname:search' government location %}" method="POST"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Find Embassies sent by</label>
    <select name="government">
        {% for entry in countries %}
            <option value="{{ entry.code }}">{{ entry.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <label>that are located in</label>
    <select name="location">
        {% for entry in countries %}
            <option value="{{ entry.code }}">{{ entry.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('appname.urls')),
    url(r'^appname/', include('appname.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

appname/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'appname'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<embassy_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.embassy_info, name='embassy_info'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>[A-Z]{3})/$', views.country_info, name='country_info'),
    url(r'^find/(?P<government>[A-Z]{3})/(?P<location>[A-Z]{3})/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # the government and location values in search regex also cause a NoReverse Match   
    url(r'^search/(?P<government>[A-Z]{3})/(?P<location>[A-Z]{3})/', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

appname/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=3)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Country'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'


class Embassy(models.Model):
    government = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="government")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="location")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Name")
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Address")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="City")
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=-1, db_column="Phone Number")
    fax_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_column="Fax Number")
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Email")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column="Link")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Embassy'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Embassies'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. The parameters to the url tag - like any template tag in fact - have to come from the context passed to the template at render time. But you're trying to use values dynamically from the form itself.

You should remove the parameters from the URL pattern altogether. You're not using them in the view anyway since you correctly get the values from request.POST.

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

...

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" ...
```

Comment: Now I'm getting and error `get_object_or_404() missing 1 required positional argument: 'klass' ` from the line `selected_government = get_object_or_404(pk=request.POST['government'])` in views.py, not sure what it means though. No where in my code have I used 'klass'

Comment: You need to tell that function what model to use: `get_object_or_404(Government, pk=request.POST['government'])`.

Comment: I think you meant `Country` but yeah you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a form with `ModelChoiceField`.

In **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import Country

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    government = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), to_field_name="code", label="Find Embassies sent by")
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), to_field_name="code", label="that are located in")
```

In **views.py**

```
from forms import SearchForm

def index(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'appname/index.html', context)


def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        govt = form.cleaned_data.get('government')
        loc = form.cleaned_data.get('location')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('appname:results', kwargs={"government": govt.code, "location": loc.code}))
    else:
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'appname/index.html', context)
```

In **appname/urls.py**
add this url

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

In **index.html**

```
<form method="post" action={% url 'appname:search' %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django URL resolver reverse takes keyword arguments as parameters

```
reverse('search', kwargs={'government':goverment.code, 'location':location.code})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You don't have namespace configured in your base app url include. So you shouldn't need appname as prefix. Updated my answer

Comment: You mean `app_name = 'appname'` ?

Comment: No where you do include in your base app urls.py something like include('appname.urls'), namespace='appname')

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't seem relevant to my issue. Especially since it's been solved now.